# UIButton Touch event is not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

```
menuView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,411, 320,49)];

UIButton *test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];
test.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 49);

[test addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[menuView addSubview:test];

[self.view addSubview:menuView];
```

I touch up inside (test ) button. but is not working . why??

Comment: does `self`implement a method named `buttonPressed:` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mixed `buttonPressed:` with `buttonPressed`.

If you implement a method like

```
- (void)buttonPressed
{
}
```

You need use

```
[test addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Note**: Pay attention on the **colon**.

But depending on what you have done, you need implement a method like

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to say that he needs to release the menuView after adding it to self.view.  `buttonWithType:` returns an autoreleased object, so the example code should definitely NOT release the button (test).  The only time you should call `release` on an object that you have created with `alloc` or `copy`.

Comment: @jonkroll you're right, it's autoreleased! I didn't noticed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for a cleaner solution you can try HMUIButtonOnTouch

source: https://github.com/HelloMihai/HMUIButtonOnTouch

```c
[self.myButton onTouchInside:^{
    NSLog(@"button tap");
}];
```